# Kudan Sample does not work well in Unity

Tags: kudan

I have new version of Kudan 1.3. I tried the KudanSample scene in Unity 5.3.4 and 5.4.1. The default tracking method is Marker. The Markerless method will not start correctly when I try to switch the method. The arrow has static coords. It looks like the gyroscope didn't start.
The Markerless method works well, when I set it as default method, but i need switching the methods in running application.
Thank you

Comment: Provide some more details.

Comment: I assume you're trying this on Android. There's a bug in the Unity plugin right now where if you detect a marker before switching to markerless tracking, something about the gyro fails to update and the markerless tracker doesn't work properly. It's in the works to be fixed, but it's a weird bug. If you're not detecting a marker and it's broken from the offset, it's likely to be because you have an old / underpowered device and it isn't able to update quickly enough to get proper gryo data. Like I said, weird bug.

Comment: I tested the KudanSample on iOS now. It works well.

Comment: This has been a problem with Kudan for at least 4 months now, so I wouldn't hold your breath for a fix! Android does not appear to be their priority, so if you are only targeting iOS I'm sure you will be fine. I have just spent 2 days trying to work around this because 'the fix' has been so long coming, but it just seems to be impossible I'm afraid

Comment: This is the behavior I have observed regarding this after a whole weekend of trying to fix it...

Comment: a) If Scene1(Markerless) is loaded FIRST and the Arrow IS PLACED, and Scene1 Unloaded AND THEN Scene2(Marker) is loaded (regardless of detection) and Scene 2 unloaded AND THEN Scene1(Markerless) is loaded again, ArbiTrackIsTracking appears to be true and the content shows immediately (but not necessarily anywhere you can see it). If you force ArbiTrackIsTracking to be false until the Arrow is placed then the content moves like the Arrow (i.e. not stuck to the floor).

Comment: b) If Scene2(Marker) is loaded FIRST (regardless of detection) and Scene 2 unloaded AND THEN Scene1(Markerless) is loaded, the Arrow will not place the Content.
c) If Scene1(Markerless) is loaded FIRST and the Arrow IS NOT PLACED, and Scene1 Unloaded AND THEN Scene2(Marker) is loaded (regardless of detection) and Scene 2 unloaded AND THEN Scene1(Markerless) is loaded, the Arrow will not place the Content.

Comment: I see this happen regardless of whether Kudan is persistent or not (so DeIniting everything- which KudanTracker does on Destroy- makes no difference).

So my feeling is that, since plugins once loaded with Unity are never unloaded, the Android plugin itself is not resetting correctly when switching from one tracking mode to another.

Is there a workaround I am missing? Or a patch?